# How do you use MovedContextHandler when running the Jetty Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I want to setup a permanent HTTP redirect in the embedded Jetty server that I'm using in my Maven build. I'm using Maven 3.0.4 and the jetty-maven-plugin version 9.0.6.v20130930. The [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/moved-context-handler.html) clearly demonstrates how to set this up in a non-embedded Jetty instance, but I can't quite figure out how to to set it up when running inside of Maven.

Here's the context XML file I'm using to do the redirect:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.MovedContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/permanently-moved-feeds</Set>
  <Set name="newContextURL">/</Set>
  <Set name="permanent">true</Set>
  <Set name="discardPathInfo">false</Set>
  <Set name="discardQuery">false</Set> 
</Configure>
```

Here is the relevant Maven pom.xml configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <resourcesBases>src/main/webapp,src/main/webapp/test-feeds</resourcesBases>                 
        </configuration>
        <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

So my specific question is how do I configure the jetty-maven-plugin so that Jetty knows where to find the context XML file in the first XML sample?

Comment: The `jetty-maven-plugin` is not for production use, it is insecure (as it co-mingles with everything maven).

Comment: That is good advice Joakim, which I am following. I am only using this setup to support integration testing. I have a scenario where I want to test what happens after an HTTP redirect. Is it possible that some of the Jetty configuration is only usable in a production installation?